Covariant derivative on a product manifold
Let $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ be smooth manifolds. Suppose $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are vector fields on $\mathcal M$ and $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are vector fields on $\mathcal N$. How does one go about defining vector fields $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(Y_1, Y_2)$ on the product manifold $\mathcal M \times \mathcal N$ (please excuse the notation), and how can we evaluate a covariant derivative
$$
\nabla_{(X_1, X_2)} (Y_1, Y_2)
$$
for an affine connection $\nabla$ on $\mathcal M \times \mathcal N$?

Do you not know what the tangent bundle of the product manifold is? I'm confused about what your question actually is. If you have connections on $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$, then you get the "direct sum" connection on their product. You just differentiate componentwise.
